# curious xticklabel style error

Tags: pgfplots, errors

I'm receiving the strangest error when trying to plot a simple graph. Let me show you - this works:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}

\pgfplotsset{every axis plot post/.append style={line width=1.0pt}}
\pgfplotsset{grid style=dotted}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}
        [clip marker paths=true,
            legend pos= south east,
            legend columns=1,
            xlabel=time $T$ / s,
            ylabel=losses $Q$ / J/cycle/m,
            xmin=0, xmax=.02,
            ymin=0, ymax=6e-2,
            xtick={0,.005,.01,.015,.02},
            %xticklabel style={/pgf/number format/.cd,sci}
            %xticklabel={%
            %   \pgfmathfloatparsenumber{\tick}%
            %   \pgfmathfloatexp{\pgfmathresult}%
            %   \pgfmathprintnumber{\pgfmathresult}%
            %}
            ]

    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

But this doesn't:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}

\pgfplotsset{every axis plot post/.append style={line width=1.0pt}}
\pgfplotsset{grid style=dotted}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}
        [clip marker paths=true,
            legend pos= south east,
            legend columns=1,
            xlabel=time $T$ / s,
            ylabel=losses $Q$ / J/cycle/m,
            xmin=0, xmax=.02,
            ymin=0, ymax=6e-2,
            xtick={0,.005,.01,.015,.02},
            xticklabel style={/pgf/number format/.cd,sci}
            %xticklabel={%
            %   \pgfmathfloatparsenumber{\tick}%
            %   \pgfmathfloatexp{\pgfmathresult}%
            %   \pgfmathprintnumber{\pgfmathresult}%
            %}
            ]

    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Any idea why? Thanks in advance

Comment: Don't use `.cd`: The change of path stays active, and all other options that apply to the tick labels and are processed afterwards are interpreted as belonging to the `/pgf/number format` directory. Just use `/pgf/number format/sci` instead of `/pgf/number format/.cd,sci`.

Comment: Could you please point out your error? I can't see any difference between the two plots but `0 \cdot 10^0` instead of a `0` for the first x-tick. What do you want to achieve? What do you mean by "doen't work"? It doesn't compile?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As pointed out by Jake, the recent version of `pgfplots` doesn't like the `.cd`. For older versions (1.5 tested) it works just fine. See the following MWE for a possible fix. It also fixes the overlapping of the y axis label (`compat=1.8`):

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[sticky-per]{siunitx}
\listfiles %shows you the version of pgfplots and tikz (if of interest)

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepgfplotslibrary{units}
\pgfplotsset{
            compat=1.8, %fixes y label position
            every axis plot post/.append style={line width=1.0pt},
            grid style=dotted,
            unit marking pre={\!\!/}, %if you want to get the same appearance as in your MWE,
            unit marking post={}, %you can change these two lines to "unit markings=slash space,"
            }

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}
        [
        clip marker paths=true,
        legend pos=south east,
        legend columns=1,
        xlabel=Time $t$, x unit=\si{\second},
        ylabel=Losses $Q$, y unit=\si{(\joule\per cycle \meter}),
        xmin=0, xmax=.02,
        ymin=0, ymax=6e-2,
        %scaled ticks=false, %if the new 1.8 ticks scaling is not desired
        xtick={0,.005,.01,.015,.02},
        xticklabel style={/pgf/number format/sci}, %changing this line removes the errors. 
        %More info about "Styles for ticks" can be seen in the pgfplots manual starting page 276
            ]    
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: You better use `compat=1.8`. If version 2.0 changes something in the code this breaks down with `newest` option. `newest` is good for the cases where you don't know what is installed but using the latest version. For example, writelatex etc. needs that.

Comment: @percusse absolutely right. I did it on sharelatex and was to lazy to check the version. @Meferdati: put \listfiles to your preamble to check your version or just update to `pgfplots` version 1.8

Comment: @Jake OK, the documentation of `pgfplots` is not really easy to read here. I have seen `format=...` as well and tried it. I am not yet sure, what the OP is asking for. Will correct that later.

Comment: OK, changed it. Thanks for your input. Do you get errors in the OPs 2. MWE? Maybe sharelatex (pgfplots v1.5.1) does not reproduce the OPs problem.

Comment: @LaRiFaRi: Yes, I get errors in the second MWE, using PGFPlots 1.8 and TikZ CVS

Comment: @Jake Strangely https://www.writelatex.com/296032ptzbrx doesn't give any errors.

Comment: Oh yes, tested it on my real system with 1.8 and CVS. Now I see the errors. I edit my answer.

Comment: @percusse Maybe for the same reason as in Sharelatex. Check the version of pgfplots. On Sharelatex it is 1.5.something and doesn't give errors.

Comment: I've installed pgfplots 1.8 and tried your example and it works perfectly. I'm still a little confused though: there are two options: "xticklabel style" and "x tick label style" - what's the difference?

Comment: On page 277 it looks like there is no difference at all. Just try it and (if nothing happens as I assume) choose the one you like more. (Please take my last MWE, I forgot to implement the units stuff the version before)

Comment: Ah, I was wondering what your commands did as I couldn't make out the difference :) Thanks again!

Comment: You may have noticed, that with 1.8 the ticks get scaled (factored out). For the x axis in your example it looks quite strange. http://mirror.switch.ch/ftp/mirror/tex/graphics/pgf/contrib/pgfplots/doc/pgfplots.pdf on page 257 describes your alternatives. I add a line to my MWE